# Magento 2: How to make bundled product disregard catalog price rule for options

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, catalog-price-rules

Is there a way to make a bundled product **options** disregard any catalog price rules that are applied to them?

Let's say I have a product like the following:

```
Product: Bundled Product 1
Type: Bundle
SKU: Bundle-1
```

Which has various options:

1. Option 1

   - Product A1 - € 10,-
   - Product A2 - € 15,-
2. Option 2

   - Product B1 - € 50,-
   - Product B2 - € 90,-

All of which are also sold seperately in the store.

If I were to make a **catalog price rule** for product **A1** for let's say a 50% discount. The price for option A1 would drop to €5,-. Which is fine when sold seperately but I do not want this price in the bundled product. Instead, the bundle should have a discount of its own (Let's say 20%) for the whole bundle. Thus ignoring the catalog price rule for A1.

Is this possible at all?

In Magento 1 I found an option called "Subproducts Discount" but this seems to be removed in Magento 2.0.1 and onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution perhaps, but it's possible by overriding the bundle product price model. With the override you can change the `getFinalPrice` to `getPrice`. Basically telling the price modal to completely disregard any price changes applied through special prices or catalog price rules for the simple products.

**di.xml**

```
...
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price" type="Vendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price" />
...
```

**Vendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Plugin\Magento\Bundle\Model\Product;

class Price extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Price
{
    public function getSelectionFinalTotalPrice(
        $bundleProduct,
        $selectionProduct,
        $bundleQty,
        $selectionQty,
        $multiplyQty = true,
        $takeTierPrice = true
    ) {

        if (null === $bundleQty) {
            $bundleQty = 1.;
        }
        if ($selectionQty === null) {
            $selectionQty = $selectionProduct->getSelectionQty();
        }

        if ($bundleProduct->getPriceType() != self::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC) return parent::getSelectionFinalTotalPrice($bundleProduct, $selectionProduct, $bundleQty, $selectionQty, $multiplyQty, $takeTierPrice);

        // Only line changed - overwrite to getPrice instead of getFinalPrice
        $price = $selectionProduct->getPrice($takeTierPrice ? $selectionQty : 1); 

        if ($multiplyQty) {
            $price *= $selectionQty;
        }

        return min(
            $price,
            $this->_applyTierPrice($bundleProduct, $bundleQty, $price),
            $this->_applySpecialPrice($bundleProduct, $price)
        );
    }
}
```

After this the individual items in a bundled product no longer used their discounted prices. We could then give a discount to the entire bundle through the special price option in the Magento 2 backend.